# react component renders twice with only one setState in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component which role is to get a category object from server with fetch, which i put in componentWillMount.
There is only one setState: it is in the componentWillMount promise callback, when the data arrives from the server.

The problem is that the component renders twice, first time, this.state.category value is the initial state of the constructor, then the second time this.state.category equals to the object recieved from the server.
How can I make the render method called only once, just after the setState ?

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Breadcrumb from './Breadcrumb';


export default class Category extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        category: {
            'published_projects':[{'images':[]}],
            'unpublished_projects':[{'images':[]}],
        }
    };

}

componentWillMount(){
    fetch(route('api.categories.show', {'slug':this.props.match.params.slug}))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({category: data});});
}

totalLikesCount(){
    return this.state.category.published_projects.reduce(( accu, item ) =>
        accu + item.likes_count ,0
    );
}
totalViewsCount(){
    return this.state.category.published_projects.reduce(( accu, item ) =>
        accu + item.views_count ,0
    );
}

totalPicturesCount(){
    return this.state.category.published_projects.reduce(( accu, item ) =>
        accu + item.images.length ,0
    );
}

render(){
    const category = this.state.category;
    console.log(category);
    return (
        <div className="w980px center">

            <div className="CategoryHeader-bg-wrapper margin-rt10 margin-lt10">
                <img alt="" src={category.picture_url}/>
                <div className="CategoryHeader-bg-gradient">
                    <h1>
                        { category.name }
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="CategoryHeader-metrics-wrapper u-boxShadow margin-rt10 margin-lt10">
                <ul className="CategoryHeader-metrics-list">
                    <li className="CategoryHeader-metrics-item txt-center">
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-label">
                            Projets
                        </span>
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-value">
                            { category.published_projects.length }
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="CategoryHeader-metrics-item txt-center">
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-label">
                            Total de mentions j'aime
                        </span>
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-value">
                            { this.totalLikesCount() }
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="CategoryHeader-metrics-item txt-center">
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-label">
                            Total des vues
                        </span>
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-value">
                            { this.totalViewsCount() }
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="CategoryHeader-metrics-item txt-center">
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-label">
                            Total des photos
                        </span>
                        <span className="CategoryHeader-metrics-value">
                            { this.totalPicturesCount() }
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: The only way to do that would be to make the data call in a parent component and not mount the `Category` component until the data exists. You can't prevent the initial render of the component. You can check and see if the data is loaded in the render method and `return null` if it doesn't exist, but it will still call the `render` function twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your code might be asking for rendering twice, indirectly:

```
// This calls to setState (but after a while)
fetch(route('api.categories.show', {'slug':this.props.match.params.slug}))
    .then(response => response.json()) // These are not called yet
    .then(data => {this.setState({category: data});}); 

// Then immediately after calling fetch, it gets to the next stages of the react lifecycles, 
// (like render)

render() ...

// Then setState gets called because it is an asynchronous call,
.then(data => {this.setState({category: data});}); 

// and setState calls to render again.
```

> The problem is that the component renders twice

You have an ugly, not recommended option which is `return null` from `render` the first time (when there is no data fetched), and return normally when you have the data, preventing the element to be rendered.

Another option you have is to catch whether or not the data is fetch in its parent, and hide the element there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on React life cycle the `componentWillMount` function is called before render ... but this does not mean that render function will wait for an `async` call inside `componentWillMount` to start rendering, so your component will render once before the fetch finish and once after the fetch is done.

If you want to make sure your component will render only if the data is available you can fetch data in parent component then you render this component only if data is available and then pass it as props to this component from parent this will guarantee a single render

Answer (score 1):

The issue here might be that `fetch` is taking some time to load the data from the server, and therefore, the DOM is loaded within that time, and gets updated once the `fetch`ed data is brought back.

To make sure the component loads, only once, add a new state variable, `isLoaded` or something, and make it false. Then, once your `fetch` is done, set it to `true`, and only render the component if `isLoaded` is true.

Here is a code sample:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        category: {
            'published_projects':[{'images':[]}],
             'unpublished_projects':[{'images':[]}],
        }
    };
}

componentWillMount(){
    fetch(route('api.categories.show', {'slug':this.props.match.params.slug}))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {this.setState({category: data, isLoaded: true});});
}
```

and finally, in the `render` method, just do a `if (this.state.isLoaded) { return(...); } else { return <p>Loading categories...</p>; }`

Comment: ok good idea, thanks. just a detail : you can't make a if statement in render method, but you can do a ternaire.

Comment: no you can make an `if` statement inside the `render` method, just cant do it within the `return` tag

Comment: @Indranil You can if you use a ternary operator within the jsx like `{isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'not loaded'}`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to **delay** the **calling** of a **render** **method** until data comes back.

The component doesn't wait for your async operations to complete before executing render. Therefore you will at minimum have 2 render calls:

- One when component first mounts
- Second when your async operation completes and the callback with setState executes

However, what you can do is **prevent the component from being added to the DOM** during the first render call by returning `null`.

You could implement this by adding a loading flag to your state and then flipping it when your data comes back... and then modifying your render method to something like this:

```
render() {
   if (this.state.loading) return (null);
   return (
      <div className="w980px center">
         ...
      </div>
   );
}
```