# ReactJS is it normal that class rendering twice while I set the state

Tags: reactjs

I was doing autocomplete class so I wanted to set the state in each changes of input value.
like:

```
state = {
  value: ""
}

render(){
  console.log("called");
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So in console I get "called" twice in each changes.
Could you please tell if it is fine or not?

Comment: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Comment: sorry for mistake, I used setState(), but still renders twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react component render method being called twice for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899323/react-component-render-method-being-called-twice-for-no-reason) - It's probably because of [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). If you're using create-react-app, IIRC it wraps your app in `<React.StrictMode>` which helps you catch errors in development mode. [This blog post](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/) explains it a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assign the values to the state that way, the recommended way for Class based components is to use
this.setState()

Comment: oh yes, my mistake, I used setState() but it still renders twice

Comment: Check these responses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893934/react-component-renders-twice-with-only-one-setstate-in-componentwillmount